# What are block chain-based anti censorship tools?

Tags: blockchain

After Telegram (a social network app or messaging service like whats-app and...) was blocked in our country, the CEO and the founder of this app told:

> We are working on blockchain-based anti-censorship tools and the
>   results will be announced in Q1 2018.

Now my question is what are blockchain-based anti-censorship tools and how they could Resist blocking(restricting) this app in a country.

After embedding this technology or tools in the Telegram, if my country urges on blocking the app, could it again block it?

Answer (score 1):

I've found [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oaKoJDWvhtlvtQEuqxgfkUHcI5np1t5Q/view). Not a lot of info though. Here's the section about TON Proxy:

> TON Proxy is a network proxy/anonymizer layer used to hide the
>   identity and IP addresses of TON nodes. Similar to I2P (Invisible Internet Project), this layer can be used to create
>   decentralized VPN services and blockchain-based TOR alternatives to
>   achieve anonymity and protect online privacy. In conjunction with the
>   TON P2P Network and TON DNS, TON Proxy can make any service, including
>   Telegram, effectively immune to censorship.